# Sublime Text 2 build via simple batch file

Tags: build, sublimetext2

I've been playing a bit with ST2 and it seems like a pretty cute editor. Unfortunatelly, its documentation is horrible.

And I'm being nice. So here's my question.

I have five files in a directory, which I usually build via a .bat file with

```
ifort file1.f90 file2.f90 file3.f90 ...
```

how can I define and execute this line on windows cmd (taking account the enviromental variables like PATH) from ST2 via  a shortcut and see the output? Is something like that even possible at this stage with ST2?

Answer (score 12):

I just made a new build like this:

```
{
    "cmd": ["$file"],
    "selector": "source.dosbatch"
}
```

Then you would put your `ifort ...` string in a .bat file and "build" that.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a step by step way to run a batch file as part of your build process:

In Sublime Text 2 go to Tools -> Build System -> New Build System

You'll be presented with a new text file with the following code in it:

```
{
"cmd": ["make"]
}
```

Now change the "make" to the exact path of your batch file so it looks something like this:

```
{
"cmd": ["D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myproject\\dostuff.bat"]
}
```

Notice you must use double backslash for windows paths.

Then save this file out as myproject.sublime-build in the default directory it asks you to save it in (should be $HOME_DIR/AppData/Roaming/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User).

Then in your project go back to Tools -> Build System and select the build system that is the same name as the file you just created (in this case it's "myproject").

Hit ctrl + b or go to tools -> build and your batch file should run and output will appear in the ST2 console.

Comment: Is there any way i can add mulitiple bat files like "cmd": ["file1.bat","file2.bat"]

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me and works with paths and files with *`whitespaces`*.

I have fixed a bug which I've posted on the ST forum [here](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/building-a-batch-file-in-the-cmd-console-problem/48946) and this here includes that fix.

---

Paste this into your **`Batch.sublime-build`** file.
This will run cmd.exe and run the code in its native console. This will accept your inputs of the batch file.

```
{
  "file_patterns": ["*.bat", "*.cmd"],
  "selector": "source.batch",
  // This runs the batch file in the cmd window.
  "shell_cmd": "start \"${file_name}\" call \"${file}\""
}
```

---

Here's a build that can be saved as **`BatchStConsole.sublime-build`**
This will run the code in Sublime Texts' console. This will not accept your inputs of the batch file. But still useful for debugging as it passes any arguments like the native CLI but just no interaction.

```
{
    "file_patterns": ["*.bat", "*.cmd"],
    "selector": "source.Batch",
    // This outputs to Sublime Texts' console
    "shell_cmd": "\"${file}\""
}
```

---

Also, in a new file `...\Data\Packages\User\Batch File.sublime-settings` you can then place this code and save. This will build these filetypes when you have automatic build as your build detection.

```
{ "extensions": [ "bat", "cmd" ] }
```

---

**Relevant help:**

https://ss64.com/nt/start.html

https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide/usage/build-systems.html

https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/build_systems.html

Comment: actually it does take inputs

Comment: What does? Running inside ST console, how?

Comment: I mean it does take script's inputs because it's pop up in separate console

Comment: Yes as per the first example in my post. Other answers here fail when the batch file contains whitespaces. That's what the `\"` are for.