# compile fortran code from sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext2

In order to produce the .o file for a fortran program I write the following command in my command prompt in windows.

> gfortran -c test.for

What I would like to do is either to access cmd from Sublime Text 2 directly or to link the previous command to a shortcut in sublime and get the output in the sublime command line.

In other discussions it is stated that you can do that for the Intel Fortran Compiler.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sublime Text 2 build via simple batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10068264/sublime-text-2-build-via-simple-batch-file)

Answer (score 1):

See this article about build systems in Sublime Text: https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide/usage/build-systems.html

Basically, you can configure Sublime so that it runs a specified command when you select the build type and press F7. The simplest type of build configuration would be a file called fortran.sublime-build with the following contents:

```
{
    "cmd": ["gfortran", "-c", "$file"]
}
```

The output of the program will appear in the Sublime Console (View -> Show Console).